# Is this correct json syntax?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm experimenting with d3 and trying now to read data from a json-file.

What I currently want to save in the json file are the words of a text with x- and y-coordinates where the words shall be written on the output .html-file.

Could you please tell me if this chosen json syntax approach is correct?

```
{"text": [
    {
      "Word": "Hi",
      "X": 300,
      "Y": 400,
    }
    {
      "Word": "Hello",
      "X": 500,
      "Y": 100,
    }
]}
```

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: No. Add a comma between items (right in the middle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not valid.

- You have some extra commas on lines 5 and 10.
- You have a missing comma on line 6.

This is valid JSON:

```
{
    "text": [
        {
            "Word": "Hi",
            "X": 300,
            "Y": 400
        },
        {
            "Word": "Hello",
            "X": 500,
            "Y": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I can see with JSONLint it's valid now :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra commas at the end of every object.